# Why SVG is not drawn without a fake update?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

The question is: why does the code need to be fake updated after generating and adding SVG via JS? It is with SVG that such other tags are added as they should. Here is an example riveted. in the first case, we generate SVG tags and add to the div. at the end there is a commented out fake update. and then a picture is added in the same way. why svg is not displayed with a commented update, and if you uncomment it, is everything fine?
This example is small but indicative. in fact, I generate a fairly large number of objects, from 2000 to about 10,000. And in this case, a dummy update takes a lot of time. what for? - This is another question, not to discuss within of this topic.

https://codepen.io/Dr_Elvis/pen/wvaMYBq

Do you know what dug up?
if you create SVG with namespace, then you do not need a fake update.
That is, if from the code above, replace:

```
let svg = document.createElement('svg');
let rect = document.createElement('rect');
```

```js
let svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
let svg = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "svg");
let rect = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'rect');
```

Then everything works as it should. at least I removed the fake update everywhere and all the elements are immediately displayed. The only question is speed, and why is this happening? Is there any documentation?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks! This documentation helped a lot. I found in the documentation that "setAttribute" should be replaced with "setAttributeNS" with the namespace "null". However, as I understand it, this applies only to the attributes of the SVG elements themselves, but does not apply to other attributes, such as "id", "class". For "href", there is an example of the NS primary that must be used - "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink". What about other attributes? Which NS should be used?

Comment: id, class are null namespace too. href is the xlink namespace, that's pretty much the only namespaced attribute you'll ever encounter and these days Firefox and Chrome support href in the null namespace too.